# Unable to get Selenium with Edge to work in a basic C# console application

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge

I am trying for the very first time to use Selenium. I would like to have a console application that opens a browser, goes to a website, and performs some actions.

To do this I looked up some tutorials. The first one I found is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp

I would like to automate Edge.

The first thing I did was get my Edge version, which incidentally decided to update when I went to the about page, something that will no doubt be a problem going forward.

I downloaded the file that corresponded to my version, although for some reason that version is x86 only while all the others are x64...

I then went to NuGet and searched for Selenium.WebDriver. Probably because I'm targeting 4.7.2 the latest version is 3.141 not version 4, but whatever. I install version 3.

I also add a nuget reference to Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools as instructed in the guide.

the guide then says use this code:

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.UseChromium = true;

var driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

However I don't have a `UseChromium` property, so this does not work.

I removed it, and used the default constructor, however this also doesn't work because it can't find the driver.

So next I passed in the path to the folder the driver is in as a parameter.

This also did not work because it is looking for a file with a different name to the one in the edge driver zip download. It looks for `microsoftwebdriver.exe` while the zip file contains `msedgedriver.exe`. Perhaps this is the reason for the error? It actually has a link in the exception when it can't find it of where to download it, however the link is dead.

I renamed the file, and ran the code. A console window appeared with debug information, and the browser opened. Success!

Next I tried to go to a website, with this code:

`driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";`

However with this I got these errors in the console window:

> Starting MSEdgeDriver 94.0.992.38
> (55a0a486d5c4c1a7374dc28a7be702fee43b3b39) on port 1307 Only local
> connections are allowed. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
> suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe. MSEdgeDriver was started
> successfully.
>
> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:1310/devtools/browser/c4e7f6f6-46d3-447c-b26b-3ad231a6122f
> [29296:584:1001/203949.853:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(119)] Every
> renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task
> provider. If a fallback task is shown, it is a bug. Please file a new
> bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
> [29296:26032:1001/203954.115:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(250)]
> crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please
> report if there is no report that this ends.
> [29296:584:1001/203954.143:ERROR:profile_manager.cc(1057)] Cannot
> create profile at path
> C:\Users\NibblyPig\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default
> [29296:584:1001/203954.143:ERROR:profile_manager.cc(2010)] Cannot
> create profile at path
> C:\Users\NibblyPig\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default
> [29296:26032:1001/203954.176:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(254)]
> crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.

The code then crashes with `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

I've tried googling the fallback task provider error and also looking at the profile error, but there is very little information and I am at a loss of what to do.

I wonder if anyone could advise what steps I might take to get this working.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

I did not face "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error when I used Selenium Edge driver but I did have my console filled with **"Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a fallback task is shown..."** message which resulted in an unwanted behaviour eventually.

What I did was downgrade Selenium package from v4.8 to v3.141.0 and downloaded the Microsoft Edge Driver.exe file to the project directory.

Then I initialized my Edge Driver the following way:

```
Options = new EdgeOptions();
Driver = new EdgeDriver(EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(".", "msedgedriver.exe"));
```

So far this works and scraping is done without any errors logged.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use WebDriver with Selenium 3, the [Selenium Tools](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools) for Microsoft Edge package must be installed.

Did you import the wrong package? Make sure it is **using Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools;** not `using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;`.

This is my simple test, and it works well:

```
public static void Main() {
            var options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.UseChromium = true;
            options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"; 
            var driverPath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop";
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(driverPath, options);
            driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/";
        }
```

**Note**: Please modify the path parameters according to your own situation.

Comment: I looked for this SeleniumTools package in NuGET and its latest stable version is deprectaed. NuGET suggests Selenium.WebDriver instead which probably causes this issue in C#